# Core Data sync with iCloud crashing randomly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, icloud

My application crashes randomly when attempting to sync to iCloud. Here is my crash log:

```
-[_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter operation:failedWithError:](1006): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Import operation encountered an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134060.)" UserInfo=0x175c6310 {exception=<PFUbiquityPeerRangeCache: 0x1762f330>
localPeerID: ZFP4XFRG6X~com~gordonmacleod~ProjectName storeName: mobile~60C52EFE-9874-4437-83B2-30C8956E5131

 Unable to resolve global object IDs: (
"<PFUbiquityGlobalObjectID: 0x188ccac0> (ZFP4XFRG6X~com~gordonmacleod~ ProjectName:Term:p1099:mobile~60C52EFE-9874-4437-83B2-30C8956E5131)",
"<PFUbiquityGlobalObjectID: 0x18a51d50> (ZFP4XFRG6X~com~gordonmacleod~ ProjectName:List:p1026:mobile~60C52EFE-9874-4437-83B2-30C8956E5131)"
 )
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score -2):

[iCloud Core Data is broken.](http://www.theverge.com/2013/3/26/4148628/why-doesnt-icloud-just-work)

You're better off serializing your data to JSON and using a [Document-based approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/DocumentArchitectureiniOS/DocumentArchitectureiniOS.html).